# how to return multiple doubles from a method

Tags: java, methods

i thought the for loop would loop in the method and return the double until it ended but it only does the process once and outputs the one number over and over till its done

```
public class CtoFTableDisplay {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String string1 = "°C";
        String string2 = "°F";

        double Celsius2 = -100;
        double fahrenheit = 0;
        fahrenheit = CtoF(Celsius2);
        //double fahrenheit = CtoF(Celsius2);
        System.out.format("%5s%9s", string1, string2);

        for (Celsius2 = -100; Celsius2 <= 100; Celsius2++) {
            System.out.format ("\n%3.1f%9.1f", Celsius2, fahrenheit);

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static double CtoF(double Celsius) {

            double [] ans = new double [200];
            double fahrenheit = 0;

            for (Celsius = -100; Celsius <= 100; Celsius++) {
                fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9/5) + 32;
            }
           return fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not changing `fahrenheit` in the loop

Comment: Your question's title is misleading.   What you are really asking about is why your program is not **printing** multiple doubles.  You don't need the method to return multiple doubles anyway.  Instead you need it to return one double (which it already does!) and then call the method multiple times ... as the answer shows you.

Comment: Actually, there is a lesson here.  If you can express what you want to happen clearly in English (or some other human language) then you are probably 75% of the way to solving the problem for yourself.   There is a technique for debugging code which is called [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ... which is an application of this idea.  Read about it.

Comment: @StephenC thank you stephen ill look into it i assume its like writing psuedocode for debugging

Comment: No. It isn't.  You need to read it, rather than guessing what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop to be this:

```
  for (Celsius2 = -100; Celsius2 <= 100; Celsius2++) {
        System.out.format ("\n%3.1f%9.1f", Celsius2, fahrenheit);
        fahrenheit = CtoF(Celsius2);
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: ive done that and it still outputs the same number in the Fahrenheit column